# Kafka consumer Behaviour

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was writing Kafka consumer and I have a query related to consumer processes.

I have a consumer with `groupId="testGroupId"` and using the same groupId I consume from multiple topics say, `"topic1"` and `"topic2"`.

Also, assume `"topic1"` is already created on broker whereas `"topic2"` is not yet created.

Now If I start the consumer I see consumer threads for `"topic1"` (which is already created) in zookeeper nodes, but I do not see any consumer thread(s) for  `"topic2"`.

My question is, will the consumer thread(s) for `"topic2"` will be created only after we create the topic on broker?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Kafka `ConsumerConnector` method like `createMessageStreamsByFilter`. Consumer will subscribe to kafka topic events and in case of new topics it will subscribe to that topic automatically.